# Flatten an array inside an array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an `Array` like this

```
[
    {
        name: "A",
        job: ["1", "2"]
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        job: ["2"]
    },
    {
        name: "C",
        job: []
    }
]
```

How do i flatten it into something like this using lodash.

```
[
    {
        name: "A",
        job: ["1"]
    },
    {
        name: "A",
        job: ["2"]
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        job: ["2"]
    },
    {
        name: "C",
        job: []
    }
]
```

The only solution coming to my mind is to iterate recursively.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use lodash for this problem? It's a problem that can very easily be solved using native javascript functions.

Comment: Hey @LarsHoldaas, The reason i preferred `lodash` over `VanillaJS` is because if in future the nesting has sub nests then `lodash` is better capable of handling it. At least it's what i thought based on normal `lodash` capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use recursion if your object isn't multiple levels deep.

Instead, you can achieve this without lodash and recursion. You could use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get each `job` array, and then create an individual object for each item within that `job` array using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{name: "A", job: ["1", "2"]}, {name: "B", job: ["2"]}, {name: "C", job: []}];

const spreadArrObj = arr => {
  return arr.flatMap(({name, job}) => {
    if(job.length < 2) return {name, job}; // if the object is empty or has one one object then return the object
    return job.map(elem => ({ // map each element in the job array to its own object
      name,
      job: [elem]
    }));
  });
}

console.log(spreadArrObj(arr));
```

See browser compatibility for `.flatMap` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thank you. I am using lodash's `_.flatMap()` so i guess it won't be a problem on the backend.

Comment: @Nithin no worries :), yeah, that should work fine then

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [{
    name: "A",
    job: ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    job: ["2"]
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    job: []
  }
];
let newArr = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var job = arr[i].job
  if (job.length > 0) {
    for (j = 0; j < job.length; j++) {
      obj = {};
      obj.name = arr[i].name;
      obj.job = [job[j]];
      newArr.push(obj);
    }
  } else {
    obj = {};
    obj.name = arr[i].name;
    obj.job = [];
    newArr.push(obj);
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is how i had implemented earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array `reduce` and check length of `job` array. If it is more than 1 then iterate the job array and create a new object and push it to the accumulator

```js
let data = [{
    name: "A",
    job: ["1", "2"]
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    job: ["2"]
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    job: []
  }
]

let newData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (curr.job.length > 1) {
    curr.job.forEach(function(item) {
      acc.push({
        name: curr.name,
        job: [item]
      })

    })
  } else {
    acc.push(curr)

  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you @brk, This solution also works and we can use it regardless of having lodash. It's just that Nick answered first and my question also had lodash requirement satisfied.